# Django calling API using view and checking if user exist before posting

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Update :

I have a view to call an api to another project. Where it book an Appointment.  After that it will sent user information(userid, first_name, etc) into their Patient table.

Right now is user will sent/POST their information into the Patient table whenever they try to create an appointment.

Reason for this is to prevent user from creating new patient object (even after it was created/exist) whenever they book an appointment. So the if else will check if user exist. If it exist, it will not create new patient object.

How to do and IF statement on checking if user exist on the API ?
Do i do a request.get on `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/Patients/` with if else ?

Here is the code:

```
@csrf_exempt
def my_django_view(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        r = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/makeapp/', data=request.POST)
    else:
        r = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/makeapp/', params=request.GET)

    if r.status_code == 201 and request.method == 'POST':
        data = r.json()
        print(data)

        # Have to post the user profile information into Patient table in another project.
        user_profile_attrs = {
            "clinicId": data["clinicId"],
            "immuneMeId": request.POST.get('userId'),
            "first_name": request.POST.get('first_name'),
            "last_name": request.POST.get('last_name'),
            "gender": request.POST.get('gender'),
            "mobileNo": request.POST.get('mobileNo'),
            "nric": request.POST.get('nric'),
        }
        # save into patient table of another project
        save_profile = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/Patients/', data=request.POST)

        return HttpResponse(r.text)
    elif r.status_code == 200:  # GET response
        return HttpResponse(r.json())
    else:
        return HttpResponse(r.json())
```

Comment: Are you passing user name in your `JSON` data or `authentication` key in your header

Comment: Which is the external API? Where should a user exist? Where do you check in your code example, if the user exists? What's the point of the last `elif` and `else` statements, if they return the very same response?

Comment: Sorry sorry, just realise the question i ask isnt explain well. I did an update above so it should be easier to see now.

Answer (score 0):

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/Patients/` in this project 
Use Django's method get_or_create().
it first gets the data if data were not found it will create the new object.
[here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) is the official Django link